# Comma inside arguments of While Loop

Tags: c, while-loop

Studying for a computer science final.

I really cannot figure this question out.

**What will be the output of this C program?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 4, 5)
    {
        printf("Loop ");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**A.** Infinite Loop

**B.** Loop Loop Loop Loop Loop

**C.** Loop Loop Loop Loop

**D.** Prints Nothing

Upon execution it prints loop for infinite times. Why is that happening? Why is there a comma inside the arguments of While loop? What does it do?

Comment: You need to research the comma operator, it's no different to if you saw `x + 7` and therefore needed to know about the addition operator :-)

Comment: Remember that in C any non-0 expression evaluates to **true**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will loop forever, because the condition of the while loop `i < 4, 5` evaluates to `5`, which is different than 0, therefore is considered `true` in `C`.

To learn more about that, read about the `comma operator`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Briefly, when the comma operator is used, all of its operands are evaluated but the whole expression takes the value of the last one. For example:

```
int val = (1, 2, 3);
printf("%d\n", val);
```

Will print `3`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in the while loop's condition is the [comma operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17), which evaluates its operands and yields the value of its right most operand.

In your case, it evaluates `i < 4` condition and discards it and then evaluates the condition to just 5. So it's essentially equivalent to:

```
while(5)
{
    printf("Loop ");
    i++;
}
```

Which obviously results in infinite loop as the condition is always true. (remember that any non-zero value is always "true" in C). There's also a possible [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) due to `i` getting incremented in the infinite loop.